# Add attachment to Outlook Mails

Tags: c#, email, uwp, outlook

i know this Question is asked multipe times. But no one had an answer of this issue. I want to add a Attachement in a Outlook Mail.

```
if (stFile != null)
{
   var stream3 = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(stFile);
   var attachment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailAttachment(
                        stFile.Name,
                        stream3);
   emailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
```

After that Outlook is starting but without a Attachement and without a error.

Sure it is a Duplicate, but I did not a find an answer how to solve the Problem.

Anyone knows a Workaround?

Maybe can any NuGet Packet solve my Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the desktop version of Outlook is unable to handle this and can only work with the *subject* and *body* of the e-mail, but cannot access the attachment. I have tested this with the UWP Mail app and it can attach the file correctly. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a workaround currently other than letting the user save the file somewhere and let her attach it manually.

The latest information I have found on this is on [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38c32901-b061-47f0-b43a-808d1aaa3993/uwp-emailmanagershowcomposenewemailasync-attachments-in-microsoft-office-365?forum=wpdevelop) where they track this as an ongoing bug.